# Is there a way to control what part of a cell's data is displayed for cells which have more text than their size?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell in Microsoft Excel with overflowing data. The overflown data is hidden because adjacent cells have some data as well. Is there some way to control what part of the cell's data is displayed?

I mean if the cell contains 15 lines of text, can I do something to make only the lowest 5 lines appear on screen?

Comment: You could use one of the text functions such as LEFT, MID, or RIGHT to create a shortened version of the text to display in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some crude control by word-wrapping the text within the cell and then choosing top, middle, or bottom vertical alignment.  Row height would control how much you see.